# ironjs: returning objects to JS

Tags: ironjs

Using Ironjs. I have a c# function registered as a JS function (via SetGlobal)

It gets called , but I want to return a value to from that function. The value is an IEnumerable of CLR objects. Using Jint this just works: I return the object and can foreach it etc, how do I do the same thing in IronJS (Why not use Jint, well it has bugs, for example it wont compile underscore.js)

EDIT: Since I am not a fluent F# person I cannot answer this question myself by reading the code. So instead I fixed Jint. However it would still be nice to know the answer

Answer (score 1):

We are still working on our .NET interop.  As such, the foreach in IronJS is not set up to enumerate IEnumerables, but instead works on CommonObject type objects.